# How can I test my code changing registers of MAX30003 in movesense?

Tags: movesense

I want to test if the code for changing register settings in MAX30003 on MAX-ECG-MONITOR works.

- Checking it via PC Simulator: Is that even possible?
- Checking it, when firmware is already on the sensor, with wbcmd or adbBridge. Unfortunately, I dont have programming jig so I would like to know how I can use Adb Bridge to read/write the register settings.

I already tried the following code:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MOVESENSE --es type get --es path Component/Max3000x --es value ''''''
```

There must be some --es settings to get the register value for the right adress, as described for wbcmd

Answer (score 0):

PC Simulator is not possible since it doesn't simulate the MAX30003 chip.

The [Component api of MAX30003](https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-device-lib/src/master/MovesenseCoreLib/resources/movesense-api/component/max3000x.yaml) contains a resource */Component/MAX3000x/Register* that can be used to read & write the registers of the MAX30003 chip while it's running (I'm not fluent with adb-bridge to know how the API is accessed using that).

**Just some words of warning about going this route:** The API in question is "non-public" API, i.e. it is possible that it will not work, it will change or it will disappear in future software versions or Movesense sensor hardware revisions. If there is something specific you need that is not part of the /Meas/HR or /Meas/ECG API's, it is a good idea to create a *Request* in the bitbucket issues.

*Full Disclosure: I work for the Movesense team*